# Running different @Sql statements depending on active profile with Spring test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-test, spring-orm

For integration testing on an application, depending on what we want to test, we have 2 separate spring profiles, one that uses H2 as the embedded database, and another one that uses MySQL embedded as database.
Each profile is called H2 and MYSQL respectively, for our tests we have a common base class called WithJsonItResources, and we want to be able to drop the database after each test is executed, this is how it looks like at the moment:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, statements = "DROP DATABASE mytestdb")
public abstract class WithJsonItResources extends WithJsonTestResources {
    protected WithJsonItResources(Class resourcesForClass) {
        super(resourcesForClass);
    }
}
```

How can I add some sort of validation or whatever, so that if the profile is H2, it runs:

```
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, statements = "DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE")
```

And if it's the MYSQL profile it runs:

```
@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, statements = "DROP DATABASE mytestdb")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of **@Profile** or **@IfProfileValue**  to decide whether H2 or MYSQL is enabled.

Also don`t hard code the statement instead read it from application.properties and resolve it using **@Value** based on active profile

Doc: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Comment: \@IfProfileValue sounds a bit like what I'm looking for, but how can I choose to call the \@Sql from \@IfProfileValue?
Or does the statements string value from \@Sql support the dynamic ${value} injection?
As I gave a concrete example class, could you share a concrete solution please? thanks!

Comment: Barath injecting ${value} properties into @Sql annotation is not supported, so your proposal is invalid

Comment: it works for me @IfProfileValue(name = "test.database",value="H2")
 @Sql(statements="${${test.database}.statements}"). properties maintained : test.database=H2
H2.statements=[DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE]